# NSUrlSession suspend and resume issue on device lock

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession

I am uploading file to server by using multipart form data with `NSURLSession`. When the application goes in background I want to suspend the request and resume when application comes in foreground again. So I simply do `[session suspend]` and `[session resume]`. This is working fine when the app goes in background only. But if the device gets locked, when going back in foreground and try to resume, I get a network connection lost error. I understand that when device is locked, all open sockets are closed and therefore the issue, but is there some way to make this work without the need of starting the upload from beginning?

Answer (score 3):

You should switch your foreground session to a background session before the app goes to background, and then there is no need to suspend it. Your file will be uploaded by OS while in background (eventually).

Comment: The problem with this is that there is requirement for the background  NSUrlSession to upload directly from file, but since we use multipart form data, we must go with suspending/resuming.

Comment: save it to a file? :D

Comment: The problem is server constraints, not client.

Comment: What kind of server constraint does not allow you to save multipart request into file and upload it? What's the difference?

Comment: The thing is that the server is as it is and at this point we cannot change the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#upload_tasks), you need to use a file to perform your background upload.

From "Background Transfer Considerations":

> Only upload tasks from a file are supported (uploading from data objects or a stream will fail after the program exits).

(In addition to that, there is no guarantee when or why your app will be terminated. Trying to avoid device locking alone won't be sufficient; there are a myriad other ways your app may be terminated.)